Can one avoid auto-closing a question due to a gold badge?
I cast the 2nd VTC to what was perhaps not the greatest question, as a duplicate.  I stand by that assessment.
But it got closed right away, without the need for further voting, due to my gold badge status in the subject.
Far as I am concerned, I would have preferred the process to have followed normal procedure, via the usual 5 votes, which is a more robust process and does not assume that I know best.
Is there something that I missed in the UI on downgrading my VTC to a regular VTC, not a Terminator-VTC?  Truly, I did do not pay any attention.  There are cases on which, maybe, such an ability would be beneficial - like on a case of obvious and rampant racism - mostly to lessen moderator workload.  But those are thankfully the exception.

p.s. as far as I understand on the basis on researching from the accepted answer, this is limited to duplicate-based closures.  Which is a relief - I am not very prone to closing on that basis anyway.

I asked for UI about this over 10 years ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625/147247

FYI if you edit the Q tag-wise, the gold badge gets 'disabled' for that particular Q, as I recently found out.

@264champagnebottlesonice which would prevent other gold badge holders who want to use their gold badge from closing it as a duplicate.

You did not miss anything. It happens without warning, and with no option to cast a "normal" vote.

I found a way, accidentally. Basically you have to edit the question, however trivially tag-wise before casting your close vote. (For instance you can remove and add back the same tag.) And then:

But this means you have to be aware you have the badge.

You can also "Terminator-Reopen", FYI, as long as it's closed as a duplicate. So, if you happen to accidentally close something and you're the first vote [in the gold-badge situation], it's easy to undo yourself.
However, in the 2nd votes scenario, even if you do that, the person who cast the VTC before you won't be able to recast theirs for a while (days) though. Nonetheless, if the Q is clearly close-worthy, someone one else will probably step in shortly to cast a similar (close) vote...

BTW, I was the 3rd VTD on that Q. In case somebody wonders why: it asks two telegraphic questions in one. No effort from the OP to clarify/focus on anything. Almost as telegraphic answer about "party politics" and saying that part of the Q is opinion-based etc.
I can see the reluctance to close as duplicate since really only half of the body of the Q was a duplicate of the target. But since that was also the title and the history Q/bit seemed tacked on, and the sole answer didn't even touch the latter half... reads too much like a FB/reddit discussion than a Q&A.

the person who cast the VTC before you won't be able to recast theirs for a while (days) though Try "never". Doing this deliberately is considered abuse of your gold badge.

@Machavity: IIRC there's a timer that resets on all close/reopen votes. I'm pretty sure I was able to vote again on the same Q after some months had passed, at least. As for it being an 'abuse', YMMV. Some diamond moderators have also done this to me, i.e. closed-reopened a Q because they 'changed their mind' or milldy edited the Q and considered the matter 'solved'.

FYI, the "timer" you're thinking of only applies to cases where your vote has "expired". Once your vote has actually been used for a question close/reopen, you can't cast the same type of vote again on that question. This is stated in the network Meta What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question, and how does question closing work? answer with "You can only vote to close once per question, unless your vote expired", and it's also explained further in the linked answer by Shog9.

This seems like an abuse of the edit system.
